# Error in my counter driving at rise edge of clock

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I made a counter that counts up to 100. The counting behavior is driven by rise edge of clock.
You can see code below.

Code for "design.sv":

```
    module counter(
      input clk,
      input rstn,
      output reg[7:0] count
    );
  
      always @ (posedge reg, negedge rstn) begin
        if(!rstn) begin
          count <= 0;
        end
    
        else if(clk) begin
          count <= count+1;
        end
      end
  
    endmodule
```

Code for testbench.sv:

```
    module test;
  
      reg clk;
      reg rstn;
      wire[7:0] count;
  
  
      initial begin
        clk = 0;
        forever #5 clk = ~clk;
      end

      counter counter_1(clk, rstn, count);
  
      initial begin
        rstn = 1;
        #0.1 rstn = 0;
        #0.1 rstn = 1;
    
        #1000 $finish;
      end
  
      initial begin
        $dumpfiles("wave.vcd");
        $dumpvars(0, test);
      end
  
    endmodule
```

Simulator gives me error like below.

```
design.sv:7: syntax error
design.sv:7: error: Malformed event control expression.
design.sv:7: error: Invalid event control.
```

I looked for statement `design.sv` 7th statement for hours.
I thought about connection of testbench `wire [7:0] count` and module `reg [7:0] count`. But, I think that port connection of module output and testbench input as reg-wire is fine.

What statement is being written wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The error message does point to the correct line, but it does not specifically tell you the exact problem.

The problem is that you mistakenly used the keyword `reg` instead of the clock signal name (`clk`) in the `always` block sensitivity list.  Change:

```
  always @ (posedge reg, negedge rstn) begin
```

to:

```
  always @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
```

I suspect you are using the `iverilog` simulator.  Sometimes other simulators can give you more meaningful error messages.  You can run your code on other simulators on EDAPlayground.  When I ran it using the Cadence simulator, it visually pointed me to the `reg` keyword on that line.

Another debugging technique is to use a text editor which has language-sensitive highlighting.  Keywords show up in different colors and/or formatting so that they are easily distinguished from signal names.

---

You have another syntax error in the testbench code.  Change `$dumpfiles` to `$dumpfile`.

Also, counter code is more commonly written as:

```
  always @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
    if(!rstn) begin
      count <= 0;
    end
    else begin
      count <= count+1;
    end
  end
```

I removed the `if (clk)` clause.

> I made a counter that counts up to 100.

Strictly speaking, it counts from 0 to 127, then rolls over to 0.